# What is the difference between "mince" and "dice"?

Tags: knife-skills

Some recipes use the term *to dice*, and other recipes use the term *to mince*.
What is the difference between *to dice*, and *to mince* used in culinary?

Comment: Please see our [cooking terms glossary](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36/cooking-terms-glossary) on meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mincing produces smaller, more irregularly-shaped items than dicing.

Dicing is generally uniform, usually 1/8 to 1/4 inch on all sides, kind of like a tiny cube.

The best way to explain the size difference is visually, check out [this link](http://startcooking.com/blog/64/How-to-Mince--Dice-and-Chop-Onions) for a great picture near the top.

Answer (score 4):

From [Cuisine at home](http://www.cuisinerecipes.com/2009/01/08/test-kitchen-tip/):

For **chopped** food, think of gambling dice, roughly 5/8-inch cubes. It’s a good cut to use when making dishes that cook awhile, like stews, soups, and stocks.

When **dicing**, keep the size of a pencil eraser in mind. You want cubes 1/4- to 3/8-inch on a side. If an ingredient is to be sautéed for short periods of time or eaten raw, as in salsa, then dice it.

**Mincing** is just cutting food into tiny bits. When you mince garlic or shallots, the small pieces spread throughout a dish, permeating it with flavor. To mince, first roughly chop or dice the food, then rock your knife back and forth over it until it’s small.

Answer (score 2):

It may be an issue of locale - in British English recipes, minced would be synonymous with ground from a American English recipe. Diced stays the same (British recipes may clarify with "finely diced" or "coarse diced")